# Не работает функция закрытия бургер меню?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Почему не срабатывает функция closeMenu?

```
const body = document.querySelector('body')
const burger = document.querySelector('.header__burger')
const burgerActive = document.querySelector('.header__burger-active')
const nav = document.querySelector('.nav')
const navActive = document.querySelector('.nav-active')

function showMenu() {
burger.classList.remove('header__burger')
burger.classList.add('header__burger-active')
nav.classList.remove('nav')
nav.classList.add('nav-active')
}
burger.addEventListener('click', showMenu)



function closeMenu() {
burgerActive.classList.remove('header__burger-active')
burgerActive.classList.add('header__burger')
navActive.classList.remove('nav-active')
navActive.classList.add('nav')
}
burgerActive.addEventListener('click', closeMenu)
```

Изначальная разметка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разметка, после срабатывания функции клика showMenu:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибки в консоли + скриншот кода
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: 1) читать легче; 2) можно копировать; 3) поиск работает. Исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: Потому что элемент с классом `.header__burger-active` появляется только после клика на бургер. На момент когда Вы задаете константу `const burgerActive = document.querySelector('.header__burger-active')` такого элемента не существует.

Comment: @Simon, спасибо ! я просто для наглядности прикрепил скриншоты, код также написал текстом. Или Вы что имели ввиду? Понял, однако я пробовал объявлять константу burgerActive = document.querySelector('.header__burger-active') после вызова клика и даже внутри функции closeMenu и все-равно не работает... Прошу подсказать все-таки, как правильно делать, и еще раз спасибо! p.s. как вы пишите в комментарий куски кода, подсвеченные серым цветом?

Answer (score 2):

У Вас там в целом довольно странная логика описана. Не за чем удалять класс при каждом клике и потом заменять его на другой класс, Вам просто нужно добавить/убрать на клик класс `active` в Вашем случае `header__burger-active`, `nav-active` и все. Для этого можно использовать `element.classList.toggle()`.

> после вызова клика и даже внутри функции closeMenu и все-равно не
> работает...

Мне интересно, каким образом это должно было работать, если `closeMenu` передается в качестве колбека в лиснер который Вы вешаете на элемент который Вы пытаетесь определить, в таком случае, внутри этого же `closeMenu`.

```js
const body = document.querySelector('body')
const burger = document.querySelector('.header__burger')
const nav = document.querySelector('.nav')

function toggleMenu() {
    burger.classList.toggle('header__burger-active');
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
}

burger.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);
```

```css
.nav {
    display: none;
}

.nav-active {
    display: block;
}

.header__burger-active {
    color: red;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="header_item-burger">
  <button class="header__burger">Burger button</button>
  <nav class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>Nav item 1</li>
      <li>Nav item 2</li>
      <li>Nav item 3</li>
      <li>Nav item 4</li>
      <li>Nav item 5</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```